# Detecting the Dominant Speaker | Twilio In Laravel

Tags: laravel, twilio-video

How can i indicate audio in laravel project .Can anyone explane me how work Dominant Speaker in twilo and implenent laravel quick.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Twilio Video, when you connect to the room, one of the [connect options](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.21.2/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions) is `dominantSpeaker`. If you set it to `true` your room will fire `dominantSpeakerChanged` events when the dominant speaker changes.

```js
Video.connect(token, {
  dominantSpeaker: true
}).then(function(room) {
  room.on('dominantSpeakerChanged', participant => {
    console.log('The new dominant speaker in the Room is:', participant);
  });
});
```

You can read more about [detecting the dominant speaker in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/detecting-dominant-speaker#javascript).

Comment: yes i already try this but dominantSpeakerChanged function call when any user add in room and unmute the audio call. but i need when speak in call then give indication who is speaking.

Comment: If the unmuting causes noise that indicates that the person unmuting is now speaking, then it is working as expected. If you think it is not working as expected, then I recommend you raise a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some evidence (a recording perhaps) of a room where this behaviour is not working as expected. That way the support and product teams can see what's happening.

Comment: In my code problem is in dominantSpeakerChanged function  when any user added in room ,unmute or mute the audio and mute unmute video then i am getting the response. But not getting any response when some one is talking. 
when any user talk during the call at that time function is not called, i need when any user speak in call then give indication who is speaking like bellow image.
Image Link - https://github.com/Soumojit1995/Issue/blob/main/Google_Meet_QA.max-2000x2000.jpg
Code Link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530349/dominant-speaker-not-working-properly-twilio-in-laravel

Comment: The code you shared there just show that there should be a message logged in the console when the dominant speaker changes. To get the behaviour you’re after, you need to write code for that too. Can you share a video of the behaviour you’re seeing?

Comment: Can you explain the details about code in dominant speaker and If you already implemented the dominant speaker related work please share me code that is very helpful for me .

Comment: I've implemented it in a project. This is [the event handler for when the speaker changes](https://github.com/philnash/phism/blob/aa494bcae12b1b728f4487a287206289e18d0954/client/src/lib/video-chat.js#L63-L80). Can you share a video example of the issue you are having with this? Your screenshot of the required feature doesn't seem to show a dominant speaker at all. Are you actually trying to show a volume/current speaking indicator on a participant?

Comment: Yes i'm  trying actually to show a volume of current speaker and remote speaker indicator on video call section .

Comment: Ok, so that's not dominant speaker at all. The dominant speaker is just the one who is speaking loudest right now. To implement volume of speakers I would advise you use the Web Audio API to process the audio streams from the users and show a volume.